# Cannot resolve symbol 'InternalAppCheckTokenProvider' errors for my android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

my project was work until today. I debugging my project and show nothing for my gradle build. but when I try to run my app on the emulator I' m getting this error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/appcheck/interop/InternalAppCheckTokenProvider;

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

android {
    namespace 'com.sao.myapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sao.myapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:21.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.5.0')


    implementation 'com.github.TutorialsAndroid:GButton:v1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.0.0'

    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.2.1'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'





    //Firebase kütüphaneleri
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'



    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'



}
```

Sorry , I'm not good for explanation. But you can ask if I did something wrong

I tried remove some firebase implemantation but it's getting worse. I don't understand tehe error. I just want to run my app properly. Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the dependency old versions to advanced versions.
like:-
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.3.0'

gradually you will see that your app will run with no error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).